# While running flutter app on physical device it is giving me the error

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 24s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: are you using the latest versions of packages in your project ?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to install the Android SDK Tools. The more easiest way is from Android Studio.

The Flutter docs show how to do:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup

> 1. Download and install Android Studio.
> 2. Start Android Studio, and go through the ‘Android Studio Setup Wizard’. This installs the latest Android SDK, Android SDK Command-line Tools, and Android SDK Build-Tools, which are required by Flutter when developing for Android.